# The use of the phrase "if not" in context

Tags: grammar

Tell me please if I used *if not* grammatically correct in the following sentence.

> Shouldn't you have been at work today? **if not**, then it is alright.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are of course other ways to use the words "if not", but your example it is being used to introduce a *condition* to the sentence:

> Shouldn't you have been at work today, if not, then it is alright.

The sentence seems fine. The only change I would make to be fussy would be to maybe use "*that*" instead of "*it*", depending on what it was you are saying is "alright" - the present situation, or the fact *that* you were not at work today.

Remember though that "if not" can be used in other ways. It can be used in place of "perhaps also", as in this example:

> He has worked here for 5 years if not 6.

Comment: It seems odd not to treat these as separate sentences that should be punctuated accordingly, either with a question mark or at least a semicolon.  *"Shouldn't you have been at work today?  If not, that's all right."*